# Use .htaccess to prevent image hotlinking except for Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Facebook

Tags: htaccess, hotlinking, scraper-sites

Can anyone create a .htaccess hotlinking rule for me allowing Google all domains (.com, co.uk, co.in, .au etc.) + bing.com + yahoo.com + facebook.com

I would do it using online hotlink htaccess generators, but in this case I have to individually add all google domains which is very time consuming. If there is any way rule in which any domain containing `.google.` are allowed to hotlinking, that might be better.

Comment: How did you get on with your [previous (related) question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126810/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-for-specific-domains-using-htaccess)? Did you find any of those answers useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent hotlinking for specific domains using .htaccess?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126810/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-for-specific-domains-using-htaccess)

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !google\.                      [NC]
Have used this method in the past, scroll down to section titled Hotlink protection allowing for multiple domains  
https://perishablepress.com/creating-the-ultimate-htaccess-anti-hotlinking-strategy/